# Executor pool limit number of threads at a time

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have a situation in which I have to run some 10,000 threads. Obviously, one machine cannot run these many threads in parallel. Is there any way by which we can ask Thread pool to run some specific number of threads in the beginning and as soon as one thread finishes, the threads which are left can start their processing ?

Comment: Have you looked at [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)?

Comment: Those aren't threads, those are _tasks_.  A thread pool uses a limited number of threads to run an unlimited number of tasks.

Comment: Title says "Executor pool". Are you saying that when searching the web for similar topics, you didn't find *any* article showing how to setup a thread pool in Java? I find that VERY hard to believe. It seem more like **you didn't do any research**. Down-voted for that reason!!

Comment: @bradimus I am using the threadPool only, I want to cap size the number of threads so CPU dont have to spend much time on context switching.

Comment: @Andreas I am using that, just not sure how to put a cap on it to prevent CPU spending much time on context switching

Comment: `TheadPoolExecutor` allows you to specify the maximum number of threads the executor can use.

Comment: Well, it turns out that this question was useful. I knew I needed `Executors.something()` but didn't know what exactly - and this was the first result with the correct answer below. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 4):

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads)` is what most likely you are looking for. There will only be as many threads running at one time as the number of threads specified. And yes one machine cannot run 10,000 threads at once in parallel, but it will be able to run them concurrently. Depending on how resource intensive each thread is, it may be more efficient in your case to use 
`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` wherein as many threads are created as needed, and threads that have finished are reused.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10000)` with `invokeAll` will throw an OutOfMemory exception with that many threads. You still could use it by submitting tasks to it instead of invoking all tasks at same time, that's I would say safer than just `invokeAll`.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case. You can have a ThreadPollExecuter with Blocking Queue. http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/how-to-use-blockingqueue-and-threadpoolexecutor-in-java/ this tutorial explains that very well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to run 10,000 tasks on a group of threads. A relatively simple approach is to create a List and then add all the tasks to the list, wrapping them in Runnable. Then, create a class that takes the list in the constructor and pops a Runnable of the list and then runs it. This activity must be synchronized in some manner. The class exits when the list is empty. Start some number of threads using this class. They'll burn down the list and then stop. Your main thread can monitor the length of the list.

Comment: That class already exists.  It is called `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`.